# Replace text file on PHP before display from URL

Tags: php, text

I have a GoldIPTV.m3u
and get.php that display GoldIPTV.m3u

i used this:

```
<?php
$file = 'GoldIPTV.m3u';

if     (file_exists    ($file)) {
    header    ('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header    ('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header    ('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=     "'.basename    ($file).'"');
    header    ('Expires: 0');
    header    ('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header    ('Pragma: public');
    header    ('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile   ($file);
    exit;
}



?>
```

GoldIPTV.m3u contain 100 lines with different links and the word (key)
i want to replace

> exact like this:  /get.php?CODE=key

i want when i type url

> domain.com/get.php?CODE=123456

it will replace (key) on the displayed page with the number witch i typed.

its possible ?
thanks for help!

Comment: Is `key` a static value consistent in all links? Is `exact like this: /get.php?CODE=key`a full line? Could you post maybe 3 actual lines?

Comment: If the key is the same for every link, you can read it in via php and do a string replace.  Otherwise you'll need to process each one individually.

Comment: yes it is static on all links

Comment: Okay, than you could just do `str_replace('CODE=key', 'CODE=123456', $string)`.

Comment: #EXTINF:-1,Channel 1
rtmp://cdn1.domain.com/iptv/ch2?code=key
#EXTINF:-1,Channel 2
rtmp://cdn1.domain.com/iptv/ch3?code=key
#EXTINF:-1,Channel 3
rtmp://cdn1.domain.com/iptv/ch4?code=key

Comment: but i need every time when change 123456 it will be displayed. on m3u file the word "key" is static. i want to change it every time from url

Comment: So change `123456` in that function to the dynamic GET/POST value. Use `@` to tag if you are directing comments to me..

Comment: @chris85 i answered with more details you can look

Comment: @chris85 look down please!

Comment: That's not an answer please remove that and update your question. I've posted an answer to what I think you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. So it sounds like you have your file

```
#EXTINF:-1,Channel 1
rtmp://cdn1.domain.com/iptv/ch2?code=key
#EXTINF:-1,Channel 2
rtmp://cdn1.domain.com/iptv/ch3?code=key
#EXTINF:-1,Channel 3
rtmp://cdn1.domain.com/iptv/ch4?code=key
```

and when you load

> /get.php?key=112233445566

You want the `key` in that file to be replaced. Is that correct?

If so try:

```
$string = file_get_contents('location');
echo nl2br(str_replace('code=key', 'code=' . $_GET['key'], $string));
```

A user could manipulate the content on your site with this approach so be careful with that. If `key` is not literal you will need to use a regex. If the case of that parameter/value can vary use [str_ireplace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php).